# Set attribute values of objects in a list equal to string values in a Map in Java

Tags: java, list, dictionary

So I have a Map that looks like so:

```
Map<String, String> properties = {"item0.label": "item0LabelValue", "item0.value":"item0Value", "item0.foregroundColor":"-1", "item0.backgroundColor":"-16738048",
"item1.label": "item1LabelValue", "item1.value":"item1Value", "item1.foregroundColor":"-1", "item1.backgroundColor":"-16738048",
"item2.label": "item2LabelValue", "item2.value":"item2Value", "item2.foregroundColor":"-1", "item2.backgroundColor":"-16738048"};
```

Both the keys and values are strings.  In other words, for this map:

```
"item1.label" is a string, not an attribute of an object (essentially poor naming convention)
```

The list will not always be the same size.  Now what I need to do is transfer all of those Strings into a list of Objects that contain attributes corresponding to .label, .value, .foregroundColor, .backgroundColor.

In this case, I'll have a list:

```
List<Object> objects = Arrays.asList(object0, object1, object2);
```

I need those objects to have values matching the strings in the map, so:

```
object0.label = "item0LabelValue";
object0.value = "item0Value";
object0.foregroundColor = "-1";
object0.backgroundColor = "-16738048";
object1.label = "item1LabelValue";
...
```

Something else to note is that not all attributes have to be given.  In other words, if the string "item0.value" is not given, then the object0.value = "item0.labelValue"

Is there a clean way of doing this?  The way to do this that I'm thinking (which seems ugly) is to create a list for each element containing "item0.", another for each item containing "item1.", etc, and then looping through each of those lists to set the value for the corresponding object.  This seems like a poor way of doing it, though.

Environment:
Java 8,
Windows 7

Comment: Seems much more like **Python** to me.

Comment: ugh habit.  Let me go back and fix the syntax

Comment: given that it was more so to show the values of the elements, not so much actual code

Comment: your title says java but this code looks like javascript.  your map code isn't valid java.

Comment: never mind.  you updated the code.  now it looks like java.

Comment: The best solution to this problem... is not to have that kind of problem. Why do you have this Map; where did it comes from? Was it generated elsewhere in your program?

Comment: it is a very old application that I am trying my best to deal with hehe but yes, the map is created elsewhere

Comment: essentially I'm trying to change it from having 4 different key:value pairs per object, to 1 object with 4 attributes so the object can be used elsewhere.  It is definitely currently ugly code, but it is what I was given to deal with

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object to hold your properties.  The object will let you define a constructor where you define rules for null or empty values.  Along with an equals and hashCode methods.  Here's some sample code to get you going

```
List<PropOject> propObjects = new ArrayList<>();

public void createObjects() {
    propObjects.add(new PropOject("label1", "value1"));
    propObjects.add(new PropOject("label2", null));
}


public class PropOject {
    private String label;
    private String value;


    public PropOject(String label, String value) {
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value != null ? value : label;
    }


    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }


    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }


    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }


    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 HashMap<Integer,MyObject> mapObjects = new HashMap<Integer,MyObject>();
 for (String key: properties.keys()){
      String[] splits = key.split('.');
      int id = Integer.valueOf(splits[0].substring(4, splits[0].length()));
      if (mapObjects.containsKey(id)){
          mapObjects.get(id).set(splits[1],properties.get(key));
      }
      else{
          MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
          myObject.set(splits[1],proterties.get(key));
          mapObjects.put(id,myObject);
      }
 }

 //Convert to list if necesseray
 List<MyObject> listObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>(mapObjects.values());

 //MyObject contains a method set(String fieldStr, String value) which based on fieldStr sets the correct field to value (or use reflection)
```

Comment: by doing this you start to lose type safety.  there's no easy to compare objects for equality or to add a compare method for sorting.

Comment: I am not comparing objects. You have the `id` which is unique.

Comment: this also doesn't satisfy the request of 'Something else to note is that not all attributes have to be given. In other words, if the string "item0.value" is not given, then the object0.value = "item0.labelValue"'

Comment: You can add very complicated logic to the `set(String fieldStr, String value)` method. You check the field name `fieldStr`, if you are expecting an int you convert to int `value` within a try catch, if you are expecting bananas you convert to bananas the value of the string `value` passed.

Comment: A very elegant method would use reflections, but for 4 fields that you actually know the names of it is a bit of an overkill :)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this actually do the trick?  It would require the class to have setters like denov posted, and I'd be creating the objects right there.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < properties.size()) {
    MyObject object = new MyObject();
    object.setLabel(properties.containsKey("item" + i + ".label") ? properties.get("item" + i + ".label") : "someDefault");
    object.setValue(properties.containsKey("item" + i + ".value") ? properties.get("item" + i + ".value") : properties.get("item" + i + ".label"));
    object.setForegroundColor(properties.containsKey("item" + i + ".foregroundColor") ? properties.get("item" + i + ".foregroundColor") : DEFAULT_FOREGROUND_COLOR);
    object.setBackgroundColor(properties.containsKey("item" + i + ".backgroundColor") ? properties.get("item" + i + ".backgroundColor") : DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    sendObjectElsewhere(object);
    i++;
}
```